# Throwing events through objects

Tags: c#, winforms, events, compact-framework

I'm developing a **Windows Mobile 5.0 or above** application with **.Net Compact Framework 2.0 SP2** and **C#**.

I have a Winform (**Form1**) with a control (**Control1**) that contains another control (**Control2**). For example, a winform with a panel and inside this panel there is a button, but in my case **Control1** and **Control2** are custom controls.

**Control2** has an event, **Click**, that is thrown when the user does click over it. This click event must be handled by **Form1**. To do it, first I handle the event on **Control1** that throws a new event that is handled on **Form1**. This my code:

**On Control1:**

```
public event EventHandler Control2Click;

private void control2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Control2Click != null)
    {
        Control2Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

**On Form1:**

```
private void control1_Control2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something interesting.
}
```

Is there a better way to handle Control2_Click directly in **Form1**? I don't know if my way has a bad performance and this kind of events can be handled better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are doing it right.  It is the correct way the bubble an event out of a nested control that isn't directly accessible from a container control.  You'd normally use the PerformClick() method to fire the Click event but this doesn't appear to be available in CF.

Perf is not an issue, calling a delegate target is very fast, a dozen nanoseconds or so on a desktop machine.  Click is a "human-time" event, anything less than 20 milliseconds is perceived as "instant".

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from hooking up the Control2 Click event directly from Form1? Does Control1 expose Control2 via a property? Or perhaps expose an event on Control1 which actually hooks up to the Control2 Click event? For example:

```
// In Control1
// Assuming Control2 is some sort of Save button, for example
public EventHandler SaveClicked
{
    add { control2.Click += value; }
    remove { control2.Click -= value; }
}
```

Note that:

- If you change the value of `control2` within `Control1`, the event handlers won't be "transferred" which would be be unfortunate
- The sender parameter in the event handler will refer to Control2, not Control1

To be honest I wouldn't expect this to be a performance problem however you handle it - it's just a delegate invocation or two.